# how to write data on online google datastore using java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I have developed a web application. It is on Google DataStore. I have to write data to the datastore. How do I do this using java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use either JDO or JPA 1.0 with Google App Engine. It uses the DataNucleus implementation.

It is provided by the GAE Eclipse plugins already. It has several limitations though.

Comment: Is there any issue like which is to prefer in from JDO/JPA ?

Comment: dude go with the standards! JPA

Comment: 1 line of Google Documentation : "You must still manually create persistence.xml and put it in war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/" !!! I think Google App Engine should provide manual configuration of Data store from Eclipse/Netbeans.